# Transactional annotation not working in spring boot 2.1.3

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, kotlin

`@Transactional` annotation is not working for me in a springboot-hibernate project. I am using the annotation configuration for which i have done the following configuration. I have tried using the `@Transactional` on method and class name in the service layer and also in the dao layer, but no luck. I think there is some  issue with the transaction manager configuration but I am unable to figure out how to configure the transaction manager in my application.

application.properties

```
#spring configuration
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
#spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
#spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.current_session_context_class=org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringSessionContext
```

dao

```
@Autowired
    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;
    @Override
    public void deleteSMS(String id) {
        logger.info("Delete sms details with id :: \"" + id + "\"");
        Session session = null;
        try {
            session = entityManagerFactory.unwrap(SessionFactory.class).openSession();
            SMSDetails smsDetails = session.get(SMSDetails.class, Long.parseLong(id));
            if (smsDetails != null)
                session.delete(smsDetails);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Error occured while deleting the sms with id :: \"" + id + "\" :: " + e.getMessage());
            throw e;
        } finally {
            if (session != null)
                session.close();
        }
    }
```

service

```
@Override
    @Transactional
    public void deleteSMS(String id) {
        smsDao.deleteSMS(id);
    }
```

I am using spring boot 2.1.3 and hibernate. I have configured the entitymanagerfactory as above and used the following to obtain session

```
session = entityManagerFactory.unwrap(SessionFactory.class).openSession();
```

but the `@Transactional` is not working

Comment: the `SessionFactory` needs to be managed by spring as well AFAIK. Also you only open the session after the transaction should have started. This is logically wrong

Answer (score 3):

You are opening a `Session` inside a `@Transactional` method. This is wrong, because when you annotate method as transactional, it is invoked inside a single session, you don't need to open another one.

Comment: i used getCurrentSession instead of openSession but the problem is still not resolved, i think the issue is with the initialization of the transaction manager. I am creating the session object by unwrapping entityManagerFactory but i am not able to figure out how to instantiate transaction manager in this case

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem
I added this annotation on my class application
@EnableTransactionManagement (proxyTargetClass = true)

And this on the method on my class service

@Transactional (rollbackFor = Exception.class)